# How to show selected value By item index ? Javascript Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular

You can see the whole code here. Here is the main problem.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/test-trainin-2?file=src/app/app.component.html

When you click on the ball, circle this green. Each circle has its own value. See this when you click on the value from the first card on all tabs and that value remains selected. I want to click on the green circle to write a value only for that card only that value element.

There i any problem with index..
This is function:

```
  selectedSet(object, index) {
    console.log(object, index);
    // this.showNote = this.showNote === index ? null : index; 
    this.selectedSetValue = object;
  }
```

I'll say it again. When I click on the green ball, I want to see only the value in that card and not on all of them.

Important:

first two row , values by ball is 0... don't be confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add a selected property for each exercise.
And it will be like local selected value.
What I did?

```
 public trainingExercises = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.trainingExercises = this.data.trainingExercises.map(el => {
      el["selected"] = 0;
      return el;
    });
}

  selectedSetValueData(obj, training) {
    training.selected = obj.value;
  }
```

and small changes in html:

`<div class="column-holder" *ngFor="let training of trainingExercises; let i = index;">`

```
<input
...
[(ngModel)]="training.selected"
/>
```

```
<div class="circle" *ngIf="!trainingSet.isTimed"
(click)="selectedSetValueData(trainingSet, training)">
```

demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/test-trainin-2-gnt42a?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: One more thing, please try to keep your code cleaner, it is really hard to read

Comment: Yes I understand for code.... but this is ...One more think...Can I set if no selected item set first item in array of sets ?

Comment: Second question why you set this onInit ? Why not my logic of code ?

Comment: Yes we can set first item of sets

Comment: I'm very interested in why you set up onInit like that? Why not how it was with me? I'm interested in the advantages of your method and the disadvantages of my method?

Comment: Because ngoninit created to initialize data for component

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227650/discussion-between-shutsman-and-bilados).